# Sed/Awk line double

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have a list like this.

- `Bob`
- `Jim`
- `Steve`

Is there a way in bash to turn that into a list like this?

- `<a href="http://example.com/Bob"> Bob`
- `<a href="http://example.com/Jim"> Jim`
- `<a href="http://example.com/Steve"> Steve`

Comment: Where is the list coming from?  That is probably the best way to start and give you some ideas.  If it is a bash array, then use of awk or sed is probably unnecessary.  If it's just an array (i.e. `list=("Bob", "Jim", "Steve")`) then you could do `for i in "${list[@]}"; do echo <a href="http://example.com/${i}">${i}</a>; done`.

Comment: It's just a text file.

Comment: Each on its own line?

Comment: Yes, each on it's own line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work fine:

```
#/usr/bin/env bash

while read n; do
    echo "<a href=\"http://example.com/${n}\">${n}</a>"
done < ${1}
```

If you made that a script, then you would call it with `./scriptname.sh filename.txt` and it just prints it to the console.  (Note: I extrapolated your question to include a `</a>` as well.)